# UnknownAttributeError for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two model as:

Customer:

```
has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['product_id'].blank? }
```

Product:

```
belongs_to :customer
```

products controller:

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :first_build)
end
```

customers controller:

```
    def customer_params
        params.require(:customer).permit(:first_build, :name, :product_id, 
                                  products_attributes: [:first_build, :customer_id])
    end
```

So in the customers controller I do this

```
@customer.products.build(:first_build => true)
```

but I get this error

```
unknown attribute 'first_build' for Prodcut
```

but when I do this  `@customer.products.build(:name => "test product name")`

it works perfectly without any error. One thing to note here, `first_build` is not a column in the products table.

Comment: I assume you meant to type `Product` not `Prodcut`... but if `first_build` is not an attribute (not a column) why are you passing it?

Comment: Yes it is Product. I just want to know if it is possible to pass attributes that are not in the table.

Comment: Oh, yes you can. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass attributes that are not in the table, you can create a "temporary" attribute which will not be stored in the table but will be available while the object is in memory.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :first_build
  ...

end
```